# How to use ng2-page-croll Scroll to load a route and then scroll

Tags: angular, web, routes, anchor

With my website setup my-app loads header+navigation+footer. In the contents I am using router-outlet to load in views based on current routes.

Some of my navigation though uses page scrolling (anchors), to scroll to various sections on the home page.

I have use NG-Page-Scroll and it works well, however these anchor links are available to me when in a different route. How can I use these links to A, route to the "home" page and then scroll to the appropriate section.

Navigation
 Nonlead - > routes to 'nonlead'
 news - scrolls to news in route 'home'
 aboutus - scrolls to aboutus in route 'home'
 events - scrolls to events in route 'home'
 calendar - scrolls to calendar in route 'home'
 join us -> routes to joinus

when in Joinus or Nonlead, how can I make the other links work by going to the home route and then scrolling to the section.

[https://github.com/munroAllie/HWA](http://github%20-%20HWA)

Comment: please show what you have done so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have asked this question too soon, the documentation on ng-page-scroll states to use RouterLink before the href.

`<li><a class="icons news" pageScroll [routerLink]="['home']" href="#news"><span>News</span></a></li>`